# How can I clean the sensor on a Panasonic LX5 compact camera?

Tags: sensor, cleaning, compact-cameras, panasonic-lumix

I've noticed there appear to be some specs of dirt on the sensor of my panasonic LX5 and was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to clean the sensor on this camera?  I found [this link](http://www.cleaningdigitalcameras.com/inspecting.html) which has some handy advice for establishing whether there is dust on the sensor. I've followed this and attached the image below:
[image]

I've seen this question: [Should I clean my camera sensor myself, or take it to a professional?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/should-i-clean-my-camera-sensor-myself-or-take-it-to-a-professional) but it applies to a DSLR which presumably would be easier to access the sensor for cleaning?

I've had a go at taking the camera apart and have got as far as removing the rear cover/LCD, but cannot tell if it's possible to remove the ribbon cables from the main circuit board or not? Maybe someone has done this before and can advise? If this is ill-advised, where would be the best place (in Paris) to get my camera serviced?

**EDIT**
Well I've managed to find these quite detailed instructions on [how to dismantle a Panasonic LX3](http://erkinson.altervista.org/en/panasonic-lumix-lx3-disassembling/), but sadly the author never got as far as exposing the sensor. Also, it seems that the connectors connecting the ribbon cables from the LCD to the main circuit board are different on the LX5 and don't have an obvious way do detach them.

Comment: I thought at first you were asking about a micro four thirds camera with an interchangeable lens, this is a whole different beast, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help as far as dismantling the camera.  However I'd venture that most of us who followed the standard procedure to locate dust on a sensor would have results the same or worse than yours.  The procedure of taking a shot against a white wall/screen and using autolevels exaggerates the spots (which is the point of the procedure, to help locate them).

The only thing that's important is how it affects real images.  I've done a similar process with my DSLR and sure enough 5-6 specks of dust.  But despite all the images I've done recently with blue skies, I haven't noticed any sensor dust.

If it is just the one spot, as @dpollitt suggested you can just get in the habit of checking that part of your image in post processing and use a little healing brush on it.

My guess is most of your daily images won't show this speck of dust, and the risk of dismantling the camera and breaking something aren't worth removing it.

Answer (score 2):

This one does NOT fall into the DYI category. Send it to Panasonic or shop for a new one!

Comment: A new sensor just because it has a speck of dust??

Comment: I wouldn't get a new one, I would just handle this in post with every image. Not optimal, but it would work.

Comment: Well, that would be if you need an excuse to get a new one ;) but my first option is good, send it for service.