# What causes these (constant) black stray lines on my photos?

Tags: nikon, dslr, artifacts, dust

There are black lines on my Nikon D3100 and I'm wondering if it is a problem with the lens or with the body itself. [image: black lines]

Comment: What method did you use to obtain the photo?  Looks like it's probably dust and lint on the sensor.  Try using a blower to remove it.  If that isn't good enough, see [What is the best way to clean the sensor on a interchangeable lens camera (mirrorless or digital SLR)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-the-sensor-on-a-interchangeable-lens-camera-mirro)

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems dust on the sensor.
Have you tried using the cleaning routine as described in [the manual](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/D3100_EN.pdf) (pp.180)?